# Multiple "grep...then..." in bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script which monitoring the output of script A, and matching keyword by "grep" command. If successfully found the keyword, echo something. Here is the script I have:

```
if script_A | grep -q 'keyword'; 
then
echo 'Found A!'
```

The script function well if only one condition. However I cannot find a way to match several keywords, and using "if...elif...else" to control the echo content for different conditions.

Here is the logic I'm trying to achieve:

```
script_A |
if grep 'keyword_A';
then echo 'Found A!'
elif grep 'keyword_B';
then echo 'Found B!'
else echo 'Found Nothing!'
```

Thanks!

Comment: It probably would be easier to do with `awk`.

Comment: I suggest using `logger` and then filter out the output using your syslog manager instead.

Comment: Each pipeline has one reader and one writer. When `script_A` writes a line, only one program can read that line. You can have that one program be something like `tee`, or you can have it be the shell capturing the output into a variable that the shell can then reproduce multiple times, but you can't have the one write have multiple copies of grep reading it directly.

Comment: BTW, how large is the output from `script_A`? If it's short enough, there may be no reason to use `grep` at all; the shell has its own built-in regex and pattern-matching; and if it's exceptionally large, that implies a need for memory-efficient answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each write can have only one reader consume if. That reader can then create multiple copies of the data it read (like `tee` does), but there has to be just one thing on the other end initially.

A more conventional approach would be to have the shell be that one reader, as in:

```
output=$(script_A)
if grep -q 'keyword_A' <<<"$output"; then
  echo 'Found A!'
elif grep -q 'keyword_B' <<<"$output"; then
  echo 'Found B!'
else
  echo 'Found nothing!'
do
```

...or, if you need to stream output continuously:

```
script_A | {
  found=0
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = *keyword_A* ]]; then
      echo 'Found A!'; found=1; break
    elif [[ $line = *keyword_B* ]]; then
      echo 'Found B!'; found=1; break
    fi
  done
  if (( found == 0 )); then
    echo 'Reached end of input and found nothing!'
  fi
}
```

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for the answer. However after test I found it's not works if the output keep generating for a while. What I want to achieve is piping all the output string to the next if conditions.

Comment: If you want to process each line individually, that would mean you'd want a `while read` loop.

Comment: Note that `grep -q` itself doesn't finish until there's been a match found, so interpreting your original code to understand the question didn't make it look like you _wanted_ continuous streaming support. (If you don't run `grep -q 'keyword_B'` until `grep -q 'keyword_A'` exits, that means you don't even start searching for B until after A has been found or the input completely finished without finding it).

Comment: @YuqiJin, ...anyhow, take a look at the edits.

Comment: thanks for the edited answer. I believe it will work, because I've also figured out the similar solution and replied in below. Anyway, thank you for the help @Charles Duffy!

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy just seeing the output of `grep` (instead of your cusom messages), you can just do:

```
if ! script_A | grep -e 'keyword_A' -e 'keyword_B'; then
    echo 'Found Nothing'
fi
```

It's somewhat difficult to directly manipulate the output of grep in the pipeline, but you could get custom messages with:

```
if ! script_A | grep -o -e 'keyword_A' -e 'keyword_B'; then
    echo 'Nothing'
fi | sed -e 's/^/Found /' -e 's/$/!/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bash rematch:

```
if [[ "demo_rematch" =~ [st] ]]; then
  echo "Matched from regexpr [st] is the letter ${BASH_REMATCH}!"
fi
```

With your single letter keywords you can do something like

```
# grep [YES] is the same as grep [ESY]
for regex in '[AB]' '[YES]' '[NO]'; do
  echo "$regex"
  if [[ "$(printf "keyword_%s\n" {A..G})" =~ keyword_$regex ]]; then
    echo "Found ${BASH_REMATCH/keyword_}!"
  else
    echo "Found Nothing!"
  fi
done
```

In real live your keywords might be more complicated. You can still use the same construction, but now I will not use the string "keyword_".

```
regex='(foo|bar|A|B|not me|no match|bingo)'
echo "$regex"
for script_A in "String with foos" "String with bar" "String with A" "String with B" "Nothing here" "Please ignore me" "and bingo"; do
  if [[ "${script_A}" =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "Found ${BASH_REMATCH}!"
  else
    echo "Found Nothing!"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone need it, I found the workable answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

 function test() {
   echo "test"
  sum=0
  while true
  do
    stat_date=`date`
    echo $stat_date
  done
}

function checkcondition() {
 while read data; do
  if [[ $data == *"10:52:59"* ]]; then
  echo "Found the time!";

  elif [[ $data == *"hi"* ]]; then
  echo "Found hi!";

  else
  echo "Nothing";

  fi
  done;

}

test | checkcondition
```

The code will keeping generating time string. And the checkcondition function will receive the output. Whenever the output string contains "10:52:59", it will print "Found the time!", otherwise print "Nothing".

Comment: Note that `function funcname() {` merges POSIX sh function declaration syntax (`funcname() {`) and legacy ksh function declaration syntax (`function funcname {`) in a manner incompatible with __both__ POSIX sh and legacy ksh. For best compatibility with modern shells, I strongly recommend the POSIX form; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: (also, `test` is the name of a shell built-in that's also a POSIX-standardized external tool, so it's best to avoid redefining it; that's an easy way to have another piece of code that runs `if test -e somefile` or such have very confusing behavior).